# data.table and "by must evaluate to list" Error

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to use the data.table package in R to dynamically generate aggregations, but I am running into an error. Below, let `my.dt` be of type `data.table`.

```
sex <- c("M","F","M","F")
age <- c(19, 23, 26, 21)
dependent.variable <- c(1400, 1500, 1250, 1100)
my.dt <- data.table(sex, age, dependent.variable)
grouping.vars <- c("sex", "age")
for (i in 1:2) {
     my.dt[,sum(dependent.variable), by=grouping.vars[i]]
}
```

If I run this, I get errors:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(my.dt, , sum(dependent.variable), by = grouping.vars[i] :
  by must evaluate to list
```

Yet the following works without error:

```
my.dt[,sum(dependent.variable), by=sex]
```

I see why the error is occurring, but I do not see how to use a vector with the `by` parameter.

Comment: You have two "grouping.vars" but are iterating from 1:5.  Am I missing something there?

Comment: Also, in your working example, sex is an object, while in your failing version it's a character.

Comment: Hey Shane, sorry, fixed it. Should be 2 not 5. That is what is not clear to me, it seems that sex is an object (??).

Comment: That's because those variables are in scope when they're used (as in if you `attach` your data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did two changes to your original code:

```
sex <- c("M","F","M","F")
age <- c(19, 23, 26, 21) 

age<-as.factor(age)

dependent.variable <- c(1400, 1500, 1250, 1100)
my.dt <- data.table(sex, age, dependent.variable)

for ( a in 1:2){
print(my.dt[,sum(dependent.variable), by=list(sex,age)[a]]) 
}
```

Numerical vector `age` should be forced into factors. As to `by` parameter, do not use quote for column names but group them into list(...). At least this is what the author has suggested.

Comment: That's interesting, and the design behind the "by" seems a bit counterintuitiv, but your code works mostly.

Only one small problem (minor, and easy to fix by just assigning names in the loop), the column names are not updated.

For variable sex, names are: sex   V1
For variable age, names are: sex   V1

Answer (score 6):

[UPDATE] 2 years after question was asked ...

On running the code in the question, `data.table` is now more helpful and returns this (using 1.8.2) :

```
Error in `[.data.table`(my.dt, , sum(dependent.variable), by = grouping.vars[i]) : 
  'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key(). Use by=list(...)
  if you can. Otherwise, by=eval(grouping.vars[i]) should work. This is for efficiency
  so data.table can detect which columns are needed.
```

and following the advice in the second sentence of error :

```
my.dt[,sum(dependent.variable), by=eval(grouping.vars[i])] 
   sex   V1
1:   M 2650
2:   F 2600
```

---

Old answer from Jul 2010 (`by` can now be `double` and `character`, though) :

Strictly speaking the `by` needs to evaluate to a list of vectors each with storage mode integer, though. So the numeric vector `age` could also be coerced to integer using `as.integer()`. This is because data.table uses radix sorting (very fast) but the radix algorithm is specifically for *integers only* (see wikipedia's entry for 'radix sort').  Integer storage for key columns and ad hoc `by` is one of the reasons data.table is fast. A factor is of course an integer lookup to unique strings.

The idea behind `by` being a `list()` of expressions is that you are not restricted to column names. It is usual to write *expressions* of column names directly in the `by`. A common one is to aggregate by month; for example :

```
DT[,sum(col1), by=list(region,month(datecol))]
```

or a very fast way to group by yearmonth is by using a non epoch based date, such as yyyymmddL as seen in some of the examples in the package, like this :

```
DT[,sum(col1), by=list(region,month=datecol%/%100L)]
```

Notice how you can name the columns inside the list() like that.

To define and reuse complex grouping expressions :

```
e = quote(list(region,month(datecol)))
DT[,sum(col1),by=eval(e)]
DT[,sum(col2*col3/col4),by=eval(e)]
```

Or if you don't want to re-evaluate the `by` expressions each time, you can save the result once and reuse the result for efficiency; if the `by` expressions themselves take a long time to calculate/allocate, or you need to reuse it many times :

```
byval = DT[,list(region,month(datecol))]
DT[,sum(col1),by=byval]
DT[,sum(col2*col3/col4),by=byval]
```

Please see http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/ for latest info and status. A new presentation will be up there soon and hoping to release v1.5 to CRAN soon too. This contains several bug fixes and new features detailed in the NEWS file. The datatable-help list has about 30-40 posts a month which may be of interest too.